# Saving image to Django Media Folder via POST request

Tags: django, python-3.x, post, django-views

I want to save the image captured via webcam in media folder
Below JS function Snapshot in html takes a snap and makes a post request to localhost server.

```
function snapshot() {
    // Draws current image from the video element into the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var Pic = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

    // Sending the image data to Servers
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addface',
    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + Pic + '" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
    },
   });
  }
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.imagedata)
    return HttpResponse(request.imagedata)
else:
    return HttpResponse('no data')
```

**Error :** REQUEST has no attribute called "imagedata" eventhough the post request has the imagedata as part of ajax post request.

I have configured media folder in settings.py. (BASE>Static>Media)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static','media')
```

Comment: Be specific about the actual issue you are facing. Add error or current output.

Comment: Added error and more clarity in ques

Comment: got it sorted. by f = open('someimage.png', 'wb'), I was doing "w" and not "wb" (write binary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data from a json payload, you have to read `request.body`.

```
import json, base64

@csrf_exempt
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        payload = json.loads(request.body)
        image_data = base64.b64decode(payload['imagedata'])
```

For files, it's more common to use "multipart/form-data" instead of json. Then you don't need to encode to and from base64. When using multipart uploads, you can access files in the django view from the `request.FILES` attribute. You would also need to change the client code. Take a look at the `FormData` web api for that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

In ajax the image will be in base64 so have a look on below code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   image_data = request.POST.get('image') #get image data
   format, imgstr = image_data.split(';base64,')
   ext = format.split('/')[-1]
   data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr)) #Image data
   myfile = "profile-"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+"." + ext  #filename
   fs = FileSystemStorage()
   filename = fs.save(myfile, data)
```

If still you have any problem then please refer https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html